# How to configure docker CLI to access docker server from minikube on Git-Bash?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, git-bash, minikube

I'm using a git bash integrated terminal on visual studio code on windows 10 pro.
If a try this command `eval $(minikube docker-env)` I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Then I try `eval '$(minikube docker-env)'` and I get this error `bash: You: command not found`

If a try `minikube docker-env` I get

```sh
You can further specify your shell with either 'cmd' or 'powershell' with the --shell flag.

SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.0.164:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\migue\.minikube\certs
SET DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.35
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

And finally if I try with `REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN '('minikube docker-env')' DO @%i` I get `bash: REM: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the configuration for the cmd.exe Shell provided by Windows.
If you want to use bash, you can manually configure it. From your output it would look like:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.0.164:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\migue\.minikube\certs"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this Command and I think it will work

```
eval '(minikube docker-env)'
```

try to check minikube environment variable using

```
$ printenv
```

if not there  try to set the environment variable for minikube

Comment: Thank you @Kirti for your help but it didn't work. I can access minikube cli from git-bash but `eval '(minikube docker-env)'` returns the same as `minikube docker-env` and it doesn't configure the necessary env variables.

Answer (score 1):

add the --shell bash to your command and it will pump out the command in the correct format

```
eval docker-machine env vmtest2 --shell bash

# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $("C:\Users\Simon\bin\docker-machine.exe" env vmtest2 --shell bash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Windows (based on @Simon Wilmann)

> Where [default] it's a VM name

Power Shell:

```
docker-machine env default --shell powershell | Invoke-Expression
```

Command Promt

```
docker-machine env default --shell cmd | Invoke-Expression
```